# java complains Array Index Out of Bound for array of array

Tags: java, arrays

What is wrong with this piece of code?

```
public class HelloWorld {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                int[] a={4,3,2,5,1,8,6,7};
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(HelloWorld.split_array(a)[0])); //expect 4325 here
        } 


    public static int[][] split_array(int[] a){
            int [][] result={};
            int mid = (int) (a.length)/2;
            result[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mid);
            result[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mid, a.length);
            return result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `result` is wrong, you don't give it any dimensions except for the fact that it's going to be an array of array.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: i don't think you need to typecast the array's length as its already an int

Comment: And just for correctness to add to what everyone else has said, your `HellowWorld("Tom")` refers to a constructor that's not present in your code. The object `h` does nothing (in the snippet), so you could get rid of that and make split_array a static method, and save on the overhead of creating an Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have initialized `result` to be an empty array. Arrays in Java do not grow automatically like in scripting languages. Instead, you need to allocate them to the correct size. In this case, you need to do:

```
int [][] result = new int[2][];
```

This will create a new array of size 2 of int arrays, then you can assign the arrays as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I find your explanation points to my pain, though answers by others are also very good!

Answer (score 4):

You have declared an array with size zero like this:

```
int [][] result={};
```

You're trying to access the first and second element of it like this:

```
result[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mid);
result[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mid, a.length);
```

...but they aren't there because the size is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not in `Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mid);`but in `result[0]`, since you had not initialized the array.`

Here is the working code:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test h = new Test();
        int[] a = { 4, 3, 2, 5, 1, 8, 6, 7 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(h.split_array(a)[0])); // expect 4325
                                                                    // here
    }
    public int[][] split_array(int[] a) {
        int[][] result = new int[2][];
        int mid = (int) (a.length) / 2;
        result[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mid);
        result[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mid, a.length);
        return result;
    }

}
```